# Why array is empty in form2

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I am a freshmen college in IT can you guys help me I am working with array I have a null value on a multidimensional array. The array is in a class while i am putting values on form 1 retrieving values on form 1 seems okay. But on form 2 I cant retrieve any value on a class because its null.

```
class Storage
{
    public string[,] Accounts = new string[100,18];

    ...
}
```

**Login.cs**

```
Storage Datas = new Storage();

private void button2_Click(object sender EventArgs e)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < Datas.Accounts.GetLength(0); p++)
    {
        if (Datas.Accounts[p, 0] != null) {
            MessageBox.Show(Datas.Accounts[p, 0]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender EventArgs e)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < Datas.Accounts.GetLength(0); p++)
    {
        if (Datas.Accounts[p, 0] != null) {
            MessageBox.Show(Datas.Accounts[p, 0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the array reset while accessing it on another form?

Comment: How on earth do you expect us to be able to help when you have not shared your code?

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question. The declarations of the arrays in both forms and the code where you are passing the array from one form to the other or where you are accessing the array of the other form.

Comment: no code? no help.

Comment: Check the picture

Comment: @chrhesmicazumic did you not read any of the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting?  Pictures of code are _explicitly_ not allowed

Comment: Please, add the code as text, not as picture! If you indent it by at least four spaces with one empty line between the English text and the code, it will automatically be formatted as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does `Datas` in `Form1.cs` come from? In `Login.cs` it is a private field. So you cannot access it from `Form1.cs`. My guess is that you have created a new `Storage` object in `Form1`.

I assume that `Form1` is the main form and that you have opened the `Login` form from `Form1`. Then you can solve the problem by passing the data between the forms through the constructor of the second form.

Add this constructor `Login.cs`:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    private readonly Storage _datas;

    public Login(Storage datas)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _datas = datas;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Here you can access: _datas.Accounts[p, 0]
    }
}
```

In `Form1` you can open the login form with

```
var login = new Login(Datas); // Pass the data as constructor parameter.
if (login.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    ...
}
```